# Failed to deserialize response message. gRPC client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc-c#

When I call my gRPC servers method, client throws an exception

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Failed to deserialize response message.")

Register my servise hier.

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseHttpLogging();
app.MapGrpcService<LocalityService>();
app.MapControllers(); 
app.Run();
```

I tried to change the versions of packages there, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in using the `app.UseHttpLogging();`. This is a bug in the asp net core internal library. It tries to log grpc requests, but due to the fact that grpc encrypts data in a special way - there is a problem of deserialization.

Microsoft has ported the hotfix to .net version 8. For now, you can fix it this way:

```
builder.UseWhen(
            ctx => ctx.Request.ContentType != "application/grpc",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.UseHttpLogging();
            }
        );
```

Below is a link to the github discussion and official microsoft replies:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39317